# Component not subscribing to Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have what I think is a very basic setup. Component A renders component B.

Component A exposes a `Subject` and in it's template passes the subject (using async pipe) to one of component B's properties:

```
@Component({
  template: "
    <div><app-comp-b [input]='s | async'></app-comp-b></div>
  "
})
class CompA {
  s: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  change(newS: string) { this.s.next(newS); }
}  

class CompB {
  @Input() input: string;
}
```

For some reason, B only gets the initial value of `s`. Subsequent calls to `change` (which create a new value in `s`) have no effect on B. That is, the value of `input` does not change (for example, if I render it in B's template).

If I subscribe manually to `s`, e.g. `s.subscribe(ss => console.log(ss));` I can see the values as they come in get printed in the console.

More than that, if I use `pipe` and `tap` to print values, nothing happens until I manually subscribe. This hints to me that the Comp B does not subscribe to `s`.

What am I doing wrong? (I am using angular 4.4.7)

Comment: Seems working for me.

Comment: [Check this StackBlitz out](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rf368c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: please add a minimal reproduction of your issue

Comment: Thanks @SiddAjmera, your example helped find the answer which I posted below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @SiddAjmera example I found the problem.

In my code, the `change()` function is not called by a button, instead it's triggered by an event fired from another component. When I use a button it starts working!

So I added a call to `detectChanges` and it is now working also from the event.

I am new to Angular but if I understand correctly, angular does not detect the change because the reference to the `Subject s` does not change. Instead it is updated with a new value. So we must force detect changes.

To add `detectChanges` I injected the change detector in the c'tor of comp A and called detect changes in `change`:

```
class CompA {
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

  s: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');

  change(newS: string) { 
    this.s.next(newS);
    this.cd.detectChanges();
  }
}
```